# Функция mail() и IE: не появляется письмо на почте

Tags: php, internet-explorer, функции

`php`-функция `mail()` работает во всех браузерах, а в `IE8` функция срабатывает без выдачи ошибок, но на почте отправленное письмо не появляется. Что за баг?

Comment: Вы уверены, что виноват ИЕ, а не челябинский метеорит?

Comment: Да, это был метеорит.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 здесь совершенно не при чем. Функции mail() абсолютно все равно с какого браузера вы вызвали обработку вашего php скрипта, это php скрипт все равно выполняет интерпретатор php.

Возможно письмо не доходит на сервер из-за неправильного header'a или из-за того, что ваш сервер не является доверенным или из-за того, что ваше письмо показалось спамом.

Есть уйма вариантов. Еще можете в логах посмотреть. Может там что-то важное пишется по этому поводу.

Comment: Простой скрипт. Просто mail("myPost@gmail.com","subject","message","From: me");
Проверил в Мозилле, Опере, Сафари, Хроме. На почте - все переданные письма, ИЕ - ни в какую. Ладно, это Денвер,  на реальном хостинге хоть такой проблемы не будет?

Comment: никакого отношения к браузерам пхп не имеееееет! запомните это! пхп выполняется на СЕРВЕРЕ!!! mail() тоже выполняется на СЕРВЕРЕ! неважно с какого устройства человек зашел...

почитайте что [такое пхп](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)

Comment: С этим я согласен и сам знаю, поэтому и вопрос задал. Сам в шоке. Сейчас еще раз проверю. В Денвере я изменил SMTP-сервер, чтобы письма отсылались на реальную почту. И вот - результат. Может быть в настройках  ИЕ?

Comment: Все, разобрался. Оказалывается функция mail() не выдает ошибку, если само содержание message будет пустым. При этом mail возвращает true, однако само письмо не отправляется.

Comment: пользуйтесь лучше чемнить другим, например PEAR Mail :)